# How to replace `set` using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm currently facing a problem where I am giving a thread a reference to a set and I want to be able to replace the set with a mocked database call. I have so far done

```
import logging
import threading
import time
from typing import Callable

from loguru import logger


class MonitorProduct:

    def __init__(self, term: str, is_alive: Callable[[str], bool]) -> None:
        self.is_alive = is_alive
        self.term = term

    def do_request(self) -> None:
        time.sleep(.1)
        while True:
            logger.info(f'Checking {self.term}')
            if not self.is_alive(self.term):
                logger.info(f'Deleting term from monitoring: "{self.term}"')
                return

            time.sleep(5)


# mocked database
def database_terms() -> set[str]:
    return {
        'hello world',
        'python 3',
        'world',
        'wth',
    }


def database_terms_2() -> set[str]:
    return {
        'what am I doing wrong',
    }


def main() -> None:
    terms: set[str] = set()

    while True:
        db_terms = database_terms()
        diff = db_terms - terms
        terms.symmetric_difference_update(db_terms)

        for url in diff:
            logger.info(f'Starting URL: {url}')
            threading.Thread(
                target=MonitorProduct(url, terms.__contains__).do_request
            ).start()

        time.sleep(2)

        # ----------------------------------------------- #

        db_terms = database_terms_2() 
        diff = db_terms - terms
        terms.symmetric_difference_update(db_terms) # <--- terms should only now contain `what am I doing wrong`

        # Start the new URLS
        for url in diff:
            logger.info(f'Starting URL 2: {url}')
            threading.Thread(
                target=MonitorProduct(url, terms.__contains__).do_request
            ).start()

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem I am now having is that when we do our first db call, it should start threads for each of terms:

```
{
  'hello world',
  'python 3',
  'world',
  'wth',
}
```

and as you can see we also send in a `terms.__contains__` for each thread.

When we do the second call of db - that set should replace the `terms` to

```
{
  'what am I doing wrong',
}
```

which should end up exiting the four running threads due to:

```
def do_request(self) -> None:
        time.sleep(.1)
        while True:
            logger.info(f'Checking {self.term}')
            if not self.is_alive(self.term):
                logger.info(f'Deleting term from monitoring: "{self.term}"')
                return

            time.sleep(5)
```

however the problem is that we cannot replace terms by doing

terms = ... because we are creating a new set and then bidning that set to the variable terms while the thread still has a reference to the old set.

My question is, how can I replace the old terms with updating to the newest set without binding a new set?

Comment: mutate the set?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Im sorry, I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: update the set object. e.g. `myset.clear(); myset.update(new_values)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but if I do that, there is a chance that will hit the `if not self.is_alive(self.term):` in the same timing which is not what I would like to do because then there is threads that were supposed to run - be exited instead and then starting a new spawn again due to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. But

```
diff = db_terms - terms
terms ^= diff  # symmetric_difference_update()
```

Isn't enough, because that just adds the new values, so it's the same as

```
terms |= diff  # update()
```

or even

```
terms |= db_terms  # update()
```

(And one of these options should be clearer to the reader than the symmetric difference, because you're not using the symmetric difference to remove anything.)

To remove the old values, you want to *also* do

```
terms &= db_terms  # intersection_update()
```

You said you're concerned about race conditions with intermediate values of the set. If you'd want to modify the set from more than one thread, you should use a mutex lock (`threading.RLock`) around it. But if you're only modifying from one thread and comparing `__contains__` in another, you can avoid a lock in CPython as long as each step of execution keeps your set in a consistent state.

Comment: Oh that is cool! Appreciate that. What I did was that I had to do a terms.clear() and then `terms |= db_terms` to replace the full set. Is that bad thing to do?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie after both lines the result is the same, though as you mentioned in a comment, in between the two lines `terms` will be empty, so there's the change of a race condition if you don't use locking. If you replace `.clear()` with `&= db_terms`, it will only remove the terms not in `db_terms`.

Comment: Oh in that vase using &= db_terms might be a better solution for me :) Will need to give that a try!

Comment: so I am correct, The correct way would be to do```db_terms = database_terms()
   diff = db_terms - terms
   terms &= db_terms
   terms |= db_terms
``` - If I am not incorrect now?

Comment: Yes, that should work.